# can i use my device name and IIS host number instead of IPv4 and IIS host number for api calls?

Tags: api, iis, ip

Currently I am using my ip and IIS host number for api calls.

For example, I use [https://192.168.1.27:100/api/values ]

where 192.168.1.27 is my ip and :100 is the host number in IIS

Now, instead of my ip "192.168.1.27" , I want to use my device name which is "DEVELOPER-1". Is that possible? If yes, how may i do that?

Comment: `:100` is called port number, not host number. To change the URL to access your web app, you need to change the site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS manager, right-click on a website, and then click Edit Bindings.

In the Site Bindings window, click Add.

In the Add Site Binding window, enter the hostname as "DEVELOPER-1".

Now, if you want to use "https://DEVELOPER-1:100" instead of the "https://192.168.1.27:100". For this, you have to open the hosts file located in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, Add "192.168.1.27 DEVELOPER-1" at the end of the file. This will tell IIS to search for the  website when https://DEVELOPER-1 url is entered.

Comment: This definitely helped. Thank you for the piece of information. It works well and good when I use the host name instead of IP from the same PC. But I am still not able to use the hostname to access it from a different device. For example, I can't access the website from my phone.

Comment: Did you get any error messages when access the website from your phone?

Comment: The error said "This site can't be reached. Check if there is a typo in developer-1"

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message? It's hard to troubleshoot your problem based on this alone.

Comment: Upon further checking, I realised that, it works properly with the device in which the IIS is running or devices connected to each other in the same network through LAN. But it doesn't work with any remote device.

Comment: How did you set up your remote device?